# React wont rerender my component when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Simple example
index.tsx holds provder
app.tsx hold consumer
When the 'next' button is click the contexts questionNumber is incremented but the QuestionDeserializer component does not render to display the questionNumber value. Why?

See the following example: https://github.com/rnnelg/reactstateproblem

Comment: Can you create codesandbox with this git repo?

Comment: You must provide the relevant [mcve] in the question itself, not just hosted elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To re render the dom you have to use the `setState` function

Comment: Have a look at my code sample. When the button is clicked a callback to a function updates the state using '

Comment: Take a look at my code sample. A callback to a function updates the state using 'setstate' and it still does not rerender the component with the correct value. It seems like the consumers state does not update.